# Gradle sync without a task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

This is unrelated to Android and to about everything I could google out for "gradle sync command".

I want to sync several directories. What works is

```
task mysync1 {
    dependsOn dep1, dep2, ...
    from "src1"
    into "dst1"
}
task mysync2 {
    dependsOn dep1, dep2, ...
    from "src2"
    into "dst2"
}
...
task mysync {
    depends on mysync1, mysync2, ....
}
```

but I hate creating tasks which I'll never call manually (especially es it clutters the output of `gradle tasks`). So I tried

```
task mysync {
    dependsOn dep1, dep2, ...
    doLast {
        sync {
            from "src1"
            into "dst1"
        }
        sync {
            from "src2"
            into "dst2"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the error

```
Could not find method from() for arguments [src1] on task ':mysync'.
```

Is there a solution? Is it a bad idea?

How it comes that it works with `copy`?

How can I find out what's allowed inside of the `sync` block (I could only find the `Sync` task)?

Comment: There is a copy() method in Project. there is no method sync(). https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:copy(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: @JBNizet This explains why I could find no documentation. :D But then, what does `sync {...}` do?

Comment: That's where my understanding of groovy's magic stops, unfortunately. All I can say is that replacing it with blabla makes gradle complain about a missing blabla method. But I can't find any sync method documented anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

> How come that it works with `copy`?

It works because [copy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:copy(groovy.lang.Closure)) is a method in [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) as [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) mentioned in the comments.

> Is there a solution?

Yes, there is a solution using the task [Sync](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.html) as there is no method called `sync`.

```groovy
task megasync() {
  dependsOn dep1,dep2....
  ['src1':'dest1','src2':'dest2',...].each{
    src,dest->
    task sync(type:Sync,overwrite:true){
      from src
      into dest
    }
    sync.execute()
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to create a method called sync that executes `Sync` task (again, `overwrite` must be set as `true`).

Also, If you want to use preserve property for each sync action then some workaround is needed in the way list is represented. Maybe as, `['src1':['dest1','preserve_variables..'],'src2':...]`

> How can I find out what's allowed inside of the sync block?
>    I tried to execute the following task:

```
task test{
    sync{
        print "Testing"  // This executes, but NPE is raised for `sync` on
                        // some other default sync methods
    }
}
```

I looked at the stacktrace and I found that `sync` is a method in [FileOperations.java](https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/gradle/gradle/HEAD/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/FileOperations.java?line=53), which has a return value. Maybe, that is the reason `print` executes and error `Could not find method sync()` is not raised instead `NPE` is raised for not returning valid object.